# C# Assign JSON DynamicObject to a Class

Tags: c#, json, class, assign, dynamicobject

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public int result_index { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
private void ReadJson()
{
    string JsonString = File.ReadAllText(MyJsonFile);
    DynamicObject jObject = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(JsonString);
    RootObject RO = (RootObject)jObject;
    ...
}
```

The line:

```
RootObject RO = (RootObject)jObject;
```

is not correct. How is possible to assign the DynamicObject to my Class?

Comment: You should deserialize it to the correct type using [`System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<RootObject>(JsonString)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547931(v=vs.111).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a `DynamicObject` to a variable of type `RootObject` because the types are not [assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3622477/3744182).  Instead, you should deserialize your JSON as a `RootObject` to begin with using [`Json.Decode<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547931(v=vs.111).aspx):

```
var RO = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<RootObject>(JsonString);
```

See also [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c) and [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) for more examples of how to deserialize to a specific type.